# Alternative to storing array in a single field of Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, field

How to avoid storing array of users in one field? I have a session table that have a field with users ids that joins the session(joinusers_id). How I should approach on inserting them? The easy way is to put them separated with comma, but I guess it isn't the most efficient way. Attached is a screenshot of my current implementation of session Table:
[image: What is currently in the table]

Comment: please explain more. not able to get u, why u want to join the session??

Comment: Why not just have a table with `session_id` and `user_id`?

Comment: If you want to let the users change their mail addresses, please go with @Jack s advice and use a primary key user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we are talking about databases and normalization.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

No, please do not use non-atomic fields, it is bad and you will get in to trouble, if you want to join such non-atomic fields.

I would suggest you are doing this:

You have users, so please create a *user* table containing all the things belonging to a user.
The user table needs a primary key: **user_mailaddress**

You have sessions, create a *session* table ... primary key: **session_id**

Now create a table *user_session*, this table has two attributes (columns) **user_mailaddress** and **session_id** using this table you can connect the two tables together.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
NATURAL_JOIN user_session
NATURAL_JOIN session
```

The natural join will join the tables, where the attributes and the contents of the attributes are comparable.

NOTE: The tables **user** and **session** are called entities. The table **user_session** is called the relation. So this is called the entity-relationship model. => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

To read it in more depth:
https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node42.html